# Already sucess to add select form dyamically , but the data from success ajax cannot be send to the new select form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a dependent dropdown, and it already works.

The problem is, the user want the second dropdown (in a different div) to be added dynamically but when we try to add a new dropdown, the new dropdown doesn't show any data when I choose value from first dropdown.

How to make the new dropdown contain data from ajax?

***P.S:*** the option value is in another html where the ajax call the html if it succeeds.

**This is the html:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dataselect").change(function() {
    var urls = "{% url 'polls:load-column' %}";
    var column = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      url: urls,
      data: {
        'column': column
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#columnselect").html(data);
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert("error occured");
      }
    });
  });
});

function appendBox() {
  $('#test').append('<select id ="columnselect" style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-color:red;text-align-last:center;"></select>')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Table Name</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <select id="dataselect" style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-color:red;text-align-last:center;">

        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-theme" onclick="appendBox()">Add</button>
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">Column Name</label>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="test">
    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <select id="columnselect" style="width:425px;background-color:white;height:30px;font-color:red;text-align-last:center;">


        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the sample AJAX response you get?

Comment: sorry @skobaljic how can i check the ajax response i get

Comment: Open you browser inspector, usually F12, than look at the Network tab, XHR (once the request was sent).

Comment: <option>
--------------------
</option>    

 <option value="DJANGO_MIGRATIONS">DJANGO_MIGRATIONS</option>

 <option value="DJANGO_CONTENT_TYPE">DJANGO_CONTENT_TYPE</option>

 <option value="AUTH_PERMISSION">AUTH_PERMISSION</option>

Comment: this one @skobaljic ?

Comment: I see now, the obvious error is you add same ID over and over again, but those should be unique - use class instead (not `id="columnselect"`).

Comment: @skobaljic woahh, yes it works! , i must change the id = "columnselect" into class="columnselect", dont know that id and class affects the ajax response .. thankyou so much

Comment: The ajax was not a problem, but repeating IDs, which is invalid. Once you go with classes, than it works fine - [take a look](https://jsfiddle.net/skobaljic/9ws7c1dq/14/).